# column to store elevations in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.2, geoserver, elevation

I am using geoserver and postgresql.
I imported raster (.tif) file to postgresql using raster2pgsql. The file thus imported creates a new table in postgresql. But when that file is previewed in geoserver using layer preview, elevations are not displayed.
Which all columns should I add in postgresql table so that it stores elevation values and thus elevations are displayed on geoserver.